# Pesquisa com a utilização do key

Tags: indexeddb

Tenho uma tabela que a `key` está como `autoIncrement`, estou precisando pesquisar e pegar a linha que identifica o código que eu passo. Quando pesquiso por outra parte do campo funciona perfeito.

A pesquisa que estou utilizando:

```
var bd = db.transaction("tbl_REUNIOES").objectStore("tbl_REUNIOES");
bd.get(w_key).onsuccess = function(event) {
```

Minha tabela:

```
 var reunioes = db.createObjectStore("tbl_REUNIOES", {autoIncrement : true});

    reunioes.createIndex("DAT_IDENT_REUNI", "DAT_IDENT_REUNI", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_DESCR_REUNI", "TXT_DESCR_REUNI", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_RESPO_PALAV", "TXT_RESPO_PALAV", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_RESPO_QGELO", "TXT_RESPO_QGELO", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_RESPO_LOUVO", "TXT_RESPO_LOUVO", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_CEPXX", "TXT_ENDER_CEPXX", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_LOGRA", "TXT_ENDER_LOGRA", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_BAIRR", "TXT_ENDER_BAIRR", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_NUMER", "TXT_ENDER_NUMER", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_COMPL", "TXT_ENDER_COMPL", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_CIDAD", "TXT_ENDER_CIDAD", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("SGL_ENDER_ESTAD", "SGL_ENDER_ESTAD", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("LAT_ENDER_REUNI", "LAT_ENDER_REUNI", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("LON_ENDER_REUNI", "LON_ENDER_REUNI", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("COD_IDULT_ATUAL", "COD_IDULT_ATUAL", {unique: false});
    reunioes.createIndex("DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", "DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", {unique: false});
```

> Preciso pegar todos os dados de determinada reunião, por exemplo a reunião `5 (Key = 5)`, preciso pegar todos os detalhes da reunião 5.

Comment: Você tem uma tabela e quais informações dela você deseja? Qual o banco de dados (ou sistema de armazenamento) utilizado? Você realiza uma consulta, passa a primary key e deseja obter quais dados?

Comment: atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: @Shura16 conseguiu ver algo ?